# Calling ant task from java programme

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to call an ant task "scp" from java. But I am getting error. I have added the jar files in eclipse class path. This is working when I execute the "build.xml" in eclipse, but not working when I am executing the java file.

My Xml File: 
build.xml

```
<project name="Project" default="copy" basedir=".">
    <target name="copy">
    <scp file="root:password@{ip}:/root/install.log"  sftp="true" trust="true" todir="."/>          
</target>
</project>
```

java code

```
    File buildFile = new File("build.xml");
    Project p = new Project();
    p.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());

    System.out.println(buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
    p.init();
    ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
    p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
    helper.parse(p, buildFile);
    p.executeTarget(p.getDefaultTarget());
```

When I execute it I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main"     C:\Users\607166161\workspace_getAFix_Deployed\pvt_npm_utility\build.xml:3: Could not create task or type of type: scp.

Ant could not find the task or a class this task relies upon.

This is common and has a number of causes; the usual 
 solutions are to read the manual pages then download and
install needed JAR files, or fix the build file: 
- You have misspelt 'scp'.
    Fix: check your spelling.
- The task needs an external JAR file to execute
 and this is not found at the right place in the classpath.
   Fix: check the documentation for dependencies.
   Fix: declare the task.
  - The task is an Ant optional task and the JAR file and/or libraries
   implementing the functionality were not found at the time you
 yourself built your installation of Ant from the Ant sources.
   Fix: Look in the ANT_HOME/lib for the 'ant-' JAR corresponding to the
  task and make sure it contains more than merely a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.
  If all it contains is the manifest, then rebuild Ant with the needed
 libraries present in ${ant.home}/lib/optional/ , or alternatively,
 download a pre-built release version from apache.org
 - The build file was written for a later version of Ant
   Fix: upgrade to at least the latest release version of Ant
 - The task is not an Ant core or optional task 
 and needs to be declared using <taskdef>.
 - You are attempting to use a task defined using 
<presetdef> or <macrodef> but have spelt wrong or not 
   defined it at the point of use

Remember that for JAR files to be visible to Ant tasks implemented
in ANT_HOME/lib, the files must be in the same directory or on the
classpath

 Please neither file bug reports on this problem, nor email the
Ant mailing lists, until all of these causes have been explored,
as this is not an Ant bug.
at     org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.getNotFoundException(UnknownElement.java:493)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:391)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:158)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:363)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
at com.bt.npm.utility.ant.AntTask.main(AntTask.java:25)
```

Comment: Do you want to execute the .jar file from inside a java coding ?

Comment: Hi Junaid, I am trying to call the ant task "scp" from java code.

Comment: I have fixed this issue. I have added the jar file "ant-jsch.jar" in class path. This solved the problem.

Comment: you can answer your own question to help others too